# How to join two entity methods as one

Tags: php, symfony, methods

Based on a private messaging app, my user entity currently have two methods to retrieve messages :

One to get the messages sent by the user

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\MessagePrive", mappedBy="emetteur")
 */
private $messagesPrivesEmis;

/**
 * @return Collection|MessagePrive[]
 */
public function getMessagesPrivesEmis(): Collection {
    return $this->messagesPrivesEmis;
}
```

and another one to get the messages received from other users

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\MessagePrive", mappedBy="recepteur")
 */
private $messagesPrivesRecus;

/**
 * @return Collection|MessagePrive[]
 */
public function getMessagesPrivesRecus(): Collection {
    return $this->messagesPrivesRecus;
}
```

The first method get the messages where `emetteur` is equal to user id, while the second get the messages where `recepteur` is equal to user id. Both are Symfony default methods

Is it possible to "merge" those two methods so it get all messages sent and received by the user in one single query?
Or should I resort to custom DQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getMerged(): Collection {
   return new ArrayCollection(
       array_merge(this->messagesPrivesEmis->toArray(), $this->messagesPrivesRecus->toArray())
   );
}
```

Comment: That  one way to do it, but two problems with this. First, messages aren't ordered. Second, it does two query. Thanks though, good to know this

Comment: IMHO it's not the entity job to merge this two varibles but use some utils class that merge two Collections function Merge (Collecion $a, Collection $b)

Comment: I see, guess I will have to do a custom query then. Wanted to be sure, thanks